# Infinite loop with sc.hasNextLine()

Tags: java, loops, input, output, infinite-loop

I am trying to work with input, but I have trouble... if I use code bellow, it hasn't end... so I am in infinite loop. and it writes something like that, even when my input has end of file:

```
...
A number has not been parsed from line n
A number has not been parsed from line n+1
A number has not been parsed from line n+2
... (infinite)
```

but I wanna instead of that this:

```
...
End of input detected!
```

Input looks like that:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
double[] numbers = new double[10];
int counter_number = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        ...
        line++;
        if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            numbers[counter_number] = sc.nextDouble();
            counter_number++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("A number has not been parsed from line "+ line);
            continue;
        }
        if (sc.hasNextLine() == false) {
            System.err.println("End of input detected!");
        }
        if (((counter_number)==10) || ((sc.hasNextLine() == false) 
                ...
            counter_number = 0;
        }
    }
```

while this loop never end? I saw tutorials where they used "while (sc.hasNextLine())" and it finished. I am beginner with java.

Comment: You never (appear) to call `sc.nextLine()` - as long as you don't consume lines, the loop will never end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] numbers = new double[10];
    int counter_number = 0;
    int line = 0;

    while (sc.hasNextLine()){

        line++;

        String thisLine = sc.nextLine();
        // this is what i wrote.

        if(thisLine.trim().isEmpty()) {
            // if the line is empty, will exit the loop.

            System.out.println("lines: "+line); // lines
            System.out.println("End of input detected!"); // end.
            break;
        }

        try {
            // if the input is a double
            numbers[counter_number] = Double.parseDouble(thisLine);
            counter_number++;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // if not
            System.out.println("A number has not been parsed from line "+ line);
            continue;
        }

        // idk
        if (counter_number == numbers.length) {
            counter_number = 0;
        }
    };

}
```

FIX. I won't close the Scanner and...  you try with this. This code end up when i type an empty line.

Comment: You should never close a scanner when using it for `System.in` as it will also close `System.in` .

Comment: This is very close what I want, but I have problem, when I have input without "empty line on end" it doesnt write "end of input deteterd" ... :(

Comment: it will write "end of input detected" when you press enter and you send an empty input.

Answer (score 0):

the only execution you have that progresses the reader is `sc.nextDouble()`,  but this happens only in case `sc.hasNextDouble()` returns true. which means that if your code will encounter a non-double input, it will be stuck forever

And as a general note - `sc.hasNextLine() == false` should be replaced with `!sc.hasNextLine()`